# Convert each row of pyspark DataFrame column to a Json string

Tags: pyspark

How to create a column with json structure based on other columns of a pyspark dataframe.

For example, I want to achieve the below in pyspark dataframe. I am able to do this on pandas dataframe as below, but how do I do the same on pyspark dataframe

```
df = {'Address': ['abc', 'dvf', 'bgh'], 'zip': [34567, 12345, 78905], 'state':['VA', 'TN', 'MA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Address', 'zip', 'state'])
lst = ['Address', 'zip']

df['new_col'] = df[lst].apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis = 1)
```

Expected output
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your pyspark dataframe is named `df`, use the `struct` function to construct a struct, and then use the `to_json` function to convert it to a json string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
....

lst = ['Address', 'zip']
df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.to_json(F.struct(*[F.col(c) for c in lst])))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I have several other columns but want json structure only on Address and Zip, so can't use *

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your needs.